# Image comparison tool for Linux

Tags: images, gui, comparison

Like [this](http://xooyoozoo.github.io/yolo-octo-bugfixes/#swallowtail&jpg=s&bpg=s), but desktop instead of web-based. Maybe Qt-based for portability. As usual, open source is preferred.

Expected usage:

```
$ compare_images a.png b.png
GUI window appears, like this:
|----------------------|
| Upper half of a.png  |
|                      |
|---(movable slider)---|
|                      |
| Lower half of b.png  |
|----------------------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi@vi I found a small app that may help you to do this job :)[DiffImg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/diffimg/)

**Features:**

- Image difference display : a yellow/red mask can overlay the
  original/modified images.
- Single/Dual panels mode.
- Statistic computation: Mean error, RMS error and min/max are
  computed.
- Several metrics can be used for computing image difference.
- Histogram of error.
- “Slideshow” : DiffImg can compare directory of image, so you can
  switch to the previous/next comparison if you have two folders with
  the same image list.

> Supported files :DifffImg uses Qt plugins to load images, so by
>   default it can read basic formats as BMP, PNG, JPG and OpenCV
>   supported formats (Tiff, OpenExR).

[image: GUI]

SOURCE:[Ubuntuhandbook.org](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/diffimg-simple-image-comparison-tool-ubuntu/)

Comment: When I saw OpenCV in dependencies, I though it can also handle not pre-aligned images.